# Installing Ubuntu on modern laptop

Tags: boot, windows, laptop

I have see over the last few year that is is getting more difficult to install ubuntu.

Usually it is no problem to boot from USB (CD's is obsolete anyway) 
But booting from USB on these machines is difficult, sine they do not seem to recognize the Ubuntu USB as bootable.

My problem is
That I am not able to install Ubuntu on any of our new laptops from 2015.

Note.
We have been using Ubuntu since 2006 (tack!!)
But lately it is getting more difficult to install on new machines,
and it used to be very easy!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to disable Secure Boot.  On most new machine, the UEFI BIOS will not boot from OS's other than what it came with or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this recently. I ran a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10. I set it up to dual boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 15.04. (It seems that it will be more difficult if you try to install an earlier distribution, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) for a tutorial.)

If you're using Windows, you can hold 'Shift' when you click restart on the start menu to access the recovery options. From there, find your way to the BIOS, probably through advanced options. Once you disable `Secure Boot`, as mentioned, hold 'Shift' again as you restart, and it should let you boot from a live USB or CD.

Good luck!

Comment: I have switch off the secure-boot and also fast-boot.